# Listview.builder not appearing correct

Tags: flutter

My Listview.builder is showing the containers in the bottom off my container, I want then to appear in the center

I tried to use shrinkWrap and putting a center but it did not work

I don't know what to do and did not find anything in the internet regarding my problem, my other listviews are working normally but this one is like this and i do not know how to fix it or how to search in the web a solution to this problem since it is a design problem and I don't really get why this is happening

tried using chatGPT to resolve his but it did not understood what I was trying to do and just gave me useless information about how the listview.builder widget works.

```
Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height:
                widget.constraints.maxHeight * widget.cartMongodb.length / 10 +
                    40,
            child: Center(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: false,
                itemCount: widget.cartMongodb.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var item = widget.cartMongodb[index]['product'];
                  var quantia = quantity[index];
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                        AppRoutes.PRODUCTSCREEN,
                        arguments: item,
                      );
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.all(widget.constraints.maxHeight * .02),
                      child: Container(
                        height: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .14,
                        width: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .14,
                              width: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .25,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                  widget.constraints.maxHeight * .02,
                                ),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .14,
                                  width: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .15,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  child: item.productPhoto != ""
                                      ? Image.network(
                                          item.productPhoto,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        )
                                      : Center(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .05),
                            Container(
                              height: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .14,
                              width: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .3,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .025,
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      item.productName,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize:
                                            widget.constraints.maxHeight * .02,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          widget.constraints.maxHeight * .002,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      item.productDetails,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize:
                                            widget.constraints.maxHeight * .019,
                                        color:
                                            const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.68),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          widget.constraints.maxHeight * .009,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "R\$${item.productPrice}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize:
                                            widget.constraints.maxHeight * .02,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                            113, 227, 154, 1),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: widget.constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                              width: widget.constraints.maxWidth * .35,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (quantity[index] > 0) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          quantity[index] = quantity[index] - 1;

                                          widget.callback(
                                            item.productPrice,
                                            false,
                                          );

                                          CartController controller =
                                              CartController();
                                          controller
                                              .incrementOrSubtractQuantity(
                                            item,
                                            "-",
                                          );
                                        });
                                        if (quantity[index] == 0) {
                                          showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return AlertDialog(
                                                title: const Text(
                                                    'Deseja Remover o produto do carrinho?'),
                                                actions: <Widget>[
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: const Text(
                                                      'Remover',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.red),
                                                    ),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      // Lógica para remover o produto
                                                      CartController
                                                          controller =
                                                          CartController();
                                                      controller
                                                          .removeProductFromCart(
                                                        item.productId,
                                                      );
                                                      widget
                                                          .deleteProduct(item);
                                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                                          .pop();
                                                      Provider.of<CartProvider>(
                                                        context,
                                                        listen: false,
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: const Text(
                                                      'Cancelar',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.grey),
                                                    ),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      CartController
                                                          controller =
                                                          CartController();
                                                      controller
                                                          .incrementOrSubtractQuantity(
                                                        item,
                                                        "+",
                                                      );
                                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                                          .pop();
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        quantity[index] =
                                                            quantity[index] + 1;

                                                        widget.callback(
                                                          item.productPrice,
                                                          true,
                                                        );
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            },
                                          );
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.remove,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "${quantia * item.unitValue}${item.measurementUnit}",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        if (item.stockQuantity >
                                            quantity[index]) {
                                          quantity[index] = quantity[index] + 1;

                                          widget.callback(
                                            item.productPrice,
                                            true,
                                          );
                                          CartController controller =
                                              CartController();
                                          controller
                                              .incrementOrSubtractQuantity(
                                            item,
                                            "+",
                                          );
                                        }
                                      });
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView.builder` is a child of `Container` that has a `height` of `widget.constraints.maxHeight * widget.cartMongodb.length / 10 + 40`, so the the list is appearing in the center of the height that you have provided, try changing the height to see what will happen. Hope this will solve the problem.